# Why is the average case for insertion in a Binary Heap O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

If the average case for deletion is lg(n), which makes sense since you have to percDown values to maintain the integrity of a heap, why is it not the same for insertion and percUping the heap? Isn't the amount of comparisons made relative to the input (n) and divided by 2?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I haven't heard this claim before. When you say "average-case," do you mean "averaged over random inputs?"

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting proposition. I have tried to do a basic computation. Please do take a look and mention if the calculation is buggy. It's basically a mechanical computation with a few assumptions.

Suppose that:

1. there are already `k` levels in a complete binary tree of `2^k-1` elements.
2. we add `2^k` more elements to make the tree have `k+1` levels.
3. the elements uniformly and randomly get situated at a level from `[1..k]`

(3) indicates that each element in the old tree is essentially replaced by a new element. Hence the number of percolations upwards will be:

```
k + 2 * (k-1) + 4 * (k - 2) + ... + 2^(k-1) * 1
= k + 2 * k + 4 * k + ... + 2^(k-1) * k - (2 + 2 * 2^2 + 3 * 2^3 + ... + (k - 1) * 2^(k-1))
= k * (2 + 4 + ... + 2^(k-1)) - (k * 2^k - 2 * (2^k - 1)) ......(a)
= k * (2^k - 1) - k * 2^k + 2 ^(k+1) - 2
= k * 2^k - k - k * 2^k + 2^(k+1) - 2
= 2^(k+1) - (k + 2)
```

(a) is computed [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20i%20*%202%5Ei,%20i%3D1%20to%20(k-1)).

Hence we have `2^k` elements that are percolated using `(2^(k+1) - (k+1) - 1)` steps. Therefore the *average cost* per element is `O((2^(k+1) - (k+1) - 1) / 2^k) = O(2 - (k+2)/2^k)` which is `O(1)`.

Hence we can assume constant cost of insertion.

**Note:** If we assume that an element will get replaced with probability `0.5`, we could factor that into the computation above and I *think* that it will lead to the division becoming close to `1`.

Comment: I haven't thought this fully through but it appears that it does not take into account that an element higher up the tree may be replaced several times when the 2^k new elements are inserted.

Comment: That would mean that the new elements have many values that are among the maxima of the old values right ? Would that be a common average case scenario ?

Comment: I have assumed that every node is eventually replaced though. So actually the bottom nodes are replaced more often in the above computation.

Comment: It is not clear to me why the elements are uniformly randomly distributed at each level. I do not see how it follows immediately from the fact that we insert them in random order.

Answer (score 0):

> why is it not the same for insertion and percUping the heap?

When you remove head (h), you swap it with last element in heap, that is lowest element (l) in longest subtree . The probability to put l into higher level of heap is considered low enough to be neglectible, because it's already lowest element of its subtree.

Special cases exist. For example, heap containing N equal integers will do head extraction in O(1). But it's not general case.

Answer (score 0):

I was just wondering the exact same thing when starting to learn about binary heaps. I wrote an implementation in C and became puzzled by this phenomena when I timed the different operations. My intuition after giving it some thought is that, just as someone else mentioned, when removing an element, its spot in the heap is replaced by the last element, i.e an element that belongs at the bottom, and will therefore be guaranteed to have to sink back down to the bottom. In my tests I only tried removal of the top element of the heap, and so these removals always lead to traversal of the whole height of the heap (log n).

Insertion on the other hand, puts the new element at the bottom and lets it float up. It is my thinking that since most of the elements of the heap are concentrated on lower levels, it is likely that the new node reaches it's correct position with only one or two jumps. Even if the node's value is the average value of the entire heap, it shouldn't typically need to jump up all the way to the vertical middle level of the heap (seeing as the bottom level of a heap containing 2^x elements, actually contains one more than half the nodes of the entire heap). Don't know if that makes sense, but it does to me :).

Now if by removal we are talking about removing any given element and not just the top one I don't see why average case there shouldn't be O(1) too, since then we should be most likely to be removing something near the bottom...